# Unable to Push Node.js Apps to CloudFoundry

Tags: node.js, cloud-foundry, vmc

I registered for a CloudFoundry account and I'm able to login to the website with my registered credentials. However, when I try to use those credentials to login via vmc I get a connection refused:

```
MyComputer$ vmc login
Attempting login to [http://api.vcap.me]
Email: <*myemail@gmail.com*>
Password: *******
Problem with login to 'http://api/vcap', HTTP exception: Errno::ECONNREFUSED:Connection refused - connect(2), try again or register for an account.
```

I assume that I need to be logged in to push because I also had the following error:

```
MyComputer$ vmc push
Would you like to deploy from the current directory? [Yn]: 
Application Name: myapp
HTTP exception: Errno::ECONNREFUSED:Connection refused - connect(2)
```

Is anyone else encountering this issue?

Comment: I've found that on some connections I just can't get in.  For example, when I'm working on my hobby project at work (on my lunch break I swear!) I can't seem to get a connection.

Answer (score 2):

It shows that you're connecting to api.vcap.me, which is typically used for a Cloud Foundry instance running on your local machine that you've installed from the source code. To push apps to CF.com, target it with vmc first:

```
vmc target https://api.cloudfoundry.com
vmc login myemail@gmail.com
```